# Find row which has unique values with respect to some of its columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My SQL table is something like this:

```
id, name, value1, value2, value3, value4
1, xyz, 1, 2, 4, 1
2, xyz, 4, 2, 4, 1
3, abc, 4, 2, 4, 1
4, abc, 4, 2, 2, 1
5, abc, 4, 2, 2, 1
```

I want to write a Sql query which returns rows which has **any** of their values (read: value1,value2,value3,value4) changed. So the result output would be:

```
id, name, value1, value2, value3, value4
1, xyz, 1, 2, 4, 1
2, xyz, 4, 2, 4, 1
4, abc, 4, 2, 2, 1
```

I understand, if I just needed values in output I could have used Distinct or Group by like:

```
select distinct value1,value2,value3,value4 from table;
```

But, here I need id and name columns too in output.

Wondering if I really need to write a subquery or create virtual/inner table to get my result. Or, there is a smarter way?

My question is not similar to [How to find out whether a table has some unique columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941049/how-to-find-out-whether-a-table-has-some-unique-columns). Let me know if you think otherwise, I can clarify.

Comment: What does "changed" mean to you?

Comment: from older value in other row. the table is sorted on id coloumn

Comment: So changed from the previous row based on id?

Comment: Why the row with the id = 2 is not on your result set?, it changed from the previous one

Comment: because I want only one row for a given value1, value2, value3, value4.

Comment: I was about to answer but why is 5 expected in the result, it's a change to 3. 1 and 3 would make sense as they were changed. 2,4,5 would as they are changes. 2 and 4 would as 5 didn't change 4. 1,3,5 though, I'm missing something.

Comment: @S.Singh Then why did you choose row 3 instead of 2? or 5 instead of 4?. Can you clarify your criteria?. We can't just guess what you want

Comment: I am updating the result output to clarify.

Comment: I want only one row for change in value1,value2,value3,value4. And it would be nice to get very first row where the change is detected. (thanks for asking questions). Let me know if the udpated output is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c513/4)

```
select *
from table
where id in (select min(id) from temp group by value1,value2,value3,value4)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!
This is what I needed, short and simple.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for your updated question, I believe that you can do it like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY value1, value2, value3, value4 ORDER BY ID)
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT id, name, value1, value2, value3, value4
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```