# SQL query to determine that values in a column are unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to write a query to just determine that the values in a column are unique?

Comment: Are you trying to determine that _all_ values are unique?

Comment: Yes, it is more of either all the columns are unique or not

Comment: Related, if not same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941049/how-to-find-out-whether-a-table-has-some-unique-columns

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN count(distinct col1)= count(col1)
THEN 'column values are unique' ELSE 'column values are NOT unique' END
FROM tbl_name;
```

Note: This only works if 'col1' does not have the data type 'ntext' or 'text'. If you have one of these data types, use 'distinct CAST(col1 AS nvarchar(4000))' (or similar) instead of 'distinct col1'.

Comment: Per @GordonLinoff comment, I suggest this answer be modified to take into account records where the column in question is NULL.

Answer (score 49):

```
select count(distinct column_name), count(column_name)
from table_name;
```

If the # of unique values is equal to the total # of values, then all values are unique.

Comment: +1. I'd like to add that this solution will not detect duplicate `NULL`s; it only works for (non-`NULL`) values.

Comment: +1, I prefer this to the boolean output of the other answers because it can show you exactly how much trouble your database is in.

Answer (score 17):

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( 
  SELECT
    column_name
  FROM
    your_table
  GROUP BY
    column_name
  HAVING
    COUNT(*)>1
)
  PRINT 'All are unique'
ELSE
  PRINT 'Some are not unique'
```

If you want to list those that aren't unique, just take the inner query and run it. HTH.

Answer (score 13):

With this following query, you have the advantage of not only seeing if your columns are unique, but you can also see which combination is most non-unique. Furthermore, because you still see frequency 1 is your key is unique, you know your results are good, and not for example simply missing; something which is less clear when using a HAVING clause.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, COUNT(*) AS Freq
FROM Table
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
ORDER BY Freq DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to return only distinct values of a column? If so, you can use the DISTINCT keyword. The syntax is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Not really return, just determine. I too am confused, but that is what being asked, hence wanted to know how to write such query

Comment: You can use something like:
    SELECT
        Column1, Column2, COUNT(*)
    FROM
        table
    GROUP BY
        Column1, Column2
    HAVING 
        COUNT(*) > 1

and if what is returned has any values, those values are the non-unique values.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if all the values are unique *and* you care about `NULL` values, then do something like this:

```
select (case when count(distinct column_name) = count(column_name) and
                  (count(column_name) = count(*) or count(column_name) = count(*) - 1)
             then 'All Unique'
             else 'Duplicates'
        end)
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select (case when count(distinct column1 ) = count(column1)
             then 'Unique'
             else 'Duplicates'
        end)
from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding you want to know which values are unique in a column. Therefore, using **select distinct** to do so doesn't solve the problem, because only lists the value as if they are unique, but they *may* **not**.

A simple solution as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name), column_name
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column_name
HAVING COUNT(column_name) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

for others who looks for the primary key   you can execute the following command (sql server) :

`exec sp_columns your_table`

and take a look a the column **TYPE_NAME** you will see a type of **int identity** , that is the primary key in your table.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use the DISTINCT keyword inside a COUNT aggregate function as shown below:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) AS some_alias FROM table_name
```

The above query will give you the count of distinct values in that column.

Answer (score -1):

this code return distinct value

```
SELECT code FROM #test
group by code
having count(distinct code)= count(code)
```

return 14 that is just unique value

[image]